# RFID as keystroke in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, keyboard-events, rfid

I have some apps in Flash that require a keystroke to navigate through scenes (on keypress 1, goto scene 1, etc.).  I have done this with some apps where I can "avoid" the physical keyboard. For example, motion detectors that type "1" when finding a motion in area 1.

I would like to know if RFID cards can be edited to "type" a single number/letter and if it would work the same way as other programs do with flash when a recognized keystroke has been pressed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an inexpensive [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/) that has a connected RFID reader they can be programmed to show up as a [Keyboard](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/KeyboardWrite).

That way moving RFID tag 'A' in range of the scanner shows up as a keyPress event with key 'A' in your Flash app. No need for a server or proxy, and much quicker to debug.

I've used a similar solution using a capacitive touch sensor.